# passing parameters using <ui:repeat>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I was using forEach for passing parameters to a function,the code is as follows

```
 <c:forEach var="q" items="#{statusBean.commentList(p.statusId)}">
```

but when I shifted to `<ui:repeat>`, the parameters were not being passed,it is giving me an exception.

```
<ui:repeat var="q" value="#{statusBean.commentList(p.statusId)}">
```

Is there any alternative to passing parameters using `<ui:repeat>`.

Comment: What is the exception . you should try to fix the error before looking for alternative

Comment: Can I pass parameter using <ui:repeat>?

Comment: ui:repeat is for looping through your data on xhtml page.You can pass parameter to the EL expression used in value attribute

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.statusId=], line 0, column -1: unexpected end of query.
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(-1@[792:1: comparisonExpressionRightOperand returns [Object node] : (n= arithmeticExpression | n= nonArithmeticScalarExpression | n= anyOrAllExpression );])
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)
 org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)

Comment: I am getting the above exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is meaningless. There is no "passing parameters by `<ui:repeat>`" and there is no "passing parameters using `<c:forEach>`". Your words might make sense in some specific context - but the context is missing.

The two tags you describe do entirely different things: one builds a component (`<ui:repeat>`), the other one pre-processes a document that will serve to build view. The difference is profound (beginning with the shape of UI that is created, the time when the binding is evaluated, interactions with saved GUI state...) and - judging from the way you ask the question - you need to understand a lot more before you tackle this specific problem. That's all right, just take your time.

But I have an honest advice: if `<c:foreach>` works for you (if only by chance), then just use it! Don't try to replace it with something altogether different (and something that you don't get).